# What is the appropriate way to refresh values on a web page after editing using a model dialog box and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, jsp, bootstrap-4

My application uses JSP/JQuery/Bootstrap.  I'll use a simplified example to help keep my question as simple as possible.

Let's say I have a "View User" page (ex. /myapp/user/55) which displays a user's properties as read-only fields (ex. "First Name", "Last Name", "Email Address") and there's an "Edit" button.

Clicking the "Edit" causes a modal dialog box to open with input fields populated with each value, and a "Save Changes" button.  You enter new values, you click the "Save Changes" button.  This causes an AJAX POST to the web server which returns a success message.

After the successful AJAX post, I hide the modal dialog box and display a success alert on the "View User" page.

The issue is, the read-only fields on the View User page have not been refreshed with the new values.

I was thinking after the successful POST, instead of just making the dialog box invisible, I could force a refresh of the view user page ... ex. just re-load "/myapp/user/55" ... but then I won't see the in-page success message, and it's also inelegant to reload the whole page.

My question is, what's the appropriate way to refresh the read-only property fields so I don't have to reload the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ajax push the user's new data, you can update the read-only fields with either JQuery or vanilla JS.

JQuery:

```
$("#user_last_name").val(@user.last_name)
```

JS:

```
const lastNameField = document.getElementById('user_last_name')
lastNameField.value = @user.last_name
```

The above assumes your fields are inputs. If the fields are spans, change the JQuery from `.val` to `.text` and the JS from `.value` to `.textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update html in related fields in some way.
For example on receive success response on POST you may use values from them (or from prepared to send data) and set innerHTML.

```js
document.forms.dialog.onsubmit = function(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();

  // make AJAX here

  window.firstName.innerHTML = ev.target.firstName.value;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstName">Prev. value</div>
<hr />
<form name="dialog">
  <input name="firstName" />
  <button type="submit" id="fakeSubmit">Mimic submit {firstName: 'Next value'}</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this in the success field of ajax call:

```
location.reload(true);
```

**Note**: for jQuery's post use this in the second argument of the function call when its success the post run  the second function call with results.

"But then I won't see the in-page success message": use jQuery's post to call a function on successful post then you can show success alert before `location.reload(true)` code (alert and refresh within the function called after successful jQuery's post).

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @moseisley ask for way to update html, and "don't have to reload the whole page".

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Thanks for the suggestion, not exactly what I wanted but it's worth thinking about.  To be clear, you're suggesting that after the successful AJAX post, I display an `alert("Save was successful")` message and then reload age after it's dismissed, correct?  I was considering an option where the POST would parse messages from the result (success and perhaps other warnings) and submit them back to the server as the page was reloading, (ex: /myapp/user/55?successMsg=All good!&warningMsg=Note two users have that same email address) and display these messages on the new page